# podman cannot pull images from registries

Tags: networking, podman

I have installed podman on the linux ec2 instance.
and when I try podman pull / run - I'm getting the below error message.

I see the issue is more related to network connectivity. please help me where to start.

Other info: the firewall service is up and running.

> [root@10.156.33.41 ~]# podman run nginx ✔
> registry.access.redhat.com/nginx:latest Trying to pull
> registry.access.redhat.com/nginx:latest... WARN[0001] Failed, retrying
> in 1s ... (1/3). Error: initializing source
> docker://registry.access.redhat.com/nginx:latest: pinging container
> registry registry.access.redhat.com: Get
> "https://registry.access.redhat.com/v2/": read tcp
> 10.156.33.41:49366->23.44.203.181:443: read: connection reset by peer WARN[0002] Failed, retrying in 1s ... (2/3). Error: initializing
> source docker://registry.access.redhat.com/nginx:latest: pinging
> container registry registry.access.redhat.com: Get
> "https://registry.access.redhat.com/v2/": read tcp
> 10.156.33.41:36680->23.44.203.181:443: read: connection reset by peer WARN[0003] Failed, retrying in 1s ... (3/3). Error: initializing
> source docker://registry.access.redhat.com/nginx:latest: pinging
> container registry registry.access.redhat.com: Get
> "https://registry.access.redhat.com/v2/": read tcp
> 10.156.33.41:36686->23.44.203.181:443: read: connection reset by peer **Error: initializing source
> docker://registry.access.redhat.com/nginx:latest: pinging container
> registry registry.access.redhat.com: Get
> "https://registry.access.redhat.com/v2/": read tcp
> 10.156.33.41:36698->23.44.203.181:443: read: connection reset by peer** [root@10.156.33.41 ~]#
>
> root@10.156.33.41 etc]# cat resolv.conf
> #Generated by NetworkManager search ec2.internal nameserver 10.156.20.2 [root@10.156.33.41 etc]#
>
> [root@10.156.33.41 etc]# podman -v podman version 4.2.0
> [root@10.156.33.41 etc]#
>
> [root@10.156.33.41 etc]# cat /etc/*rel*  NAME="Red Hat Enterprise
> Linux" VERSION="8.7 (Ootpa)" ID="rhel" ID_LIKE="fedora"
> VERSION_ID="8.7" PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8" PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat
> Enterprise Linux 8.7 (Ootpa)" ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
> CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8::baseos"
> HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
> DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://access.redhat.com/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/" BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"
>
> REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8"
> REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.7 REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat
> Enterprise Linux" REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.7" NAME="Red Hat
> Enterprise Linux Server" VERSION="7.9 (Maipo)" ID="rhel"
> ID_LIKE="fedora" VARIANT="Server" VARIANT_ID="server" VERSION_ID="7.9"
> PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux" ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
> CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.9:GA:server"
> HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
> BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"
>
> REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
> REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.9 REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat
> Enterprise Linux" REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.9" cat:
> /etc/prelink.conf.d: Is a directory Red Hat Enterprise Linux release
> 8.7 (Ootpa) Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.7 (Ootpa) cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8::baseos  [root@10.156.33.41 etc]#

Comment: Are you able to access `https://registry.access.redhat.com/v2/` yourself from the command line (using e.g. `curl` or `wget`)?

Comment: [root@10.156.33.41~]# curl https://registry.access.redhat.com/v2/
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to registry.access.redhat.com:443

Comment: So it looks like whatever your problem is it isn't a Podman problem. It looks like something is blocking or interrupting your ability to connecto to `registry.access.redhat.com`.

Comment: Yes, need to troubleshoot this issue. any insights on where to start with ?

Comment: It is a certificate issue. You must install the certificate to connect to `registry.access.redhat.com`

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openshift_container_platform/3.11/html/configuring_clusters/install-config-configuring-red-hat-registry    --> is this related ? 

I'm getting the same error for docker.io too.

Comment: @Max -  would you mind suggesting how to install the certs please ? 
also , I didn't do any kind of cert related changes after installing the docker in my past experience, the docker pull/run works normally once you authenticate using docker login . 

how and why it is different this time ??

Comment: It seems that the catalog is empty `https://registry.access.redhat.com/v2/_catalog` OR it has another endpoint to browse. Probably the article you post is correct; the `registry.access.redhat.com` no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was because we were not able to reach the repos to pull the images.
Our security teams whitelisted the repo urls then we were able to pull the images.

Thanks.